# How to receive stats about the current position of a stepper motor on arduino with python

Tags: python, arduino

I am a rookie to Arduino and Python and I am currently stuck and would need some help. My goal is to control stepper motors with python, where the stepper motors are connected to an Arduino. The Arduino is connected to my pc via a serial connection. I've sent commands to the Arduino via Python and the arduino successfully translates these commands to drive the motors.

The problem occurs when I want to execute several movements. When I try to run several movements, python sends several movement commands to the Arduino at the same time. The first command gets executed and when the motor is still spinning the follow up commands will be ignored. This causes the motors not stacking, and makes it impossible to execute each movement.

I want to use python to send the commands step by step and just at the right moment. I thought of the following workaround:
I want to send another command from Python to the Arduino which extracts the current position of the stepper motor. With this information about the absolute position, I might be able to time my python commands. The Arduino setup uses the accelstepper.h library.

In my case, the line "stepperX.currentPosition()" will get the current position in Arduino. This works in Arduino and can be printed out with the Arduino serial monitor.
Unfortunately, with Python, I can't extract that information yet.

With python, I use the following code.
Sending is fine, the receiving part is not working for me.

```
#Python
    # this is what i use as function in the python code to extract the current position
        def chkpos_x(self):
        self.__send('chkposX')
        positioning = self.__receive()
        return positioning

    # this his how python sends to the arduino with an established connection
        def send(self, message):
            if not self.is_connected():
                print('Can\'t send message. Connect to a port first.')
                return

            print('Trying to send to ' + self.__serial_port.name + ': \"' + message + '\"')
            try:
                # str.encode converts a string to ASCII bytes:
                self.__serial_port.write(str.encode(message))
            except (SerialException, SerialTimeoutException) as e:
                self.__serial_port = None
                print('Failed to send to serial port ' + self.__serial_port.name + ': ' + str(e))

    # this is how python should receive the serial communication
     def receive(self):
            if self.__serial_port is None:
                print('Can\'t receive: Connect to a port first.')
                return ''
            try:
                # readline() stops the program - unless a timeout is specified when constructing the serial port (see connect())
                instrument_answer_bytes = self.__serial_port.readline()
                instrument_answer = instrument_answer_bytes.decode('utf-8')
                #print('Instrument on serial port ' + self.__serial_port.name + ' answered: \"' + instrument_answer + '\"')
                return instrument_answer
            except (SerialException, SerialTimeoutException) as e:
                self.__serial_port = None
                #print('Failed to receive from serial port ' + self.__serial_port.name + ': ' + str(e))
                return ''
#Arduino
    #The arduino converts commands from python with this:
    String receivedData;
    String command;
    int    param;
    void initSerialConnection() {
      Serial.begin(9600);
    }
    void interpretIncomingData() {
      if(!Serial.available()) {
        return;
      }
     receivedData = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
     command = getStringSegment(receivedData, ' ', 0);
      if (command.equals("chkposX")){
          chkposX();
          return;
          }

    # when it gets the 'chkposX' command it should execute the following
    void chkposX() {
    long XPOS = stepperX.currentPosition(); 
    Serial.print(XPOS);
    }
```

I assume that common devices like a sensor actually "react" on a specific command sent to them via serial communication and return some answer.
I guess this is not the case with my Python/Arduino situation and that I have to extract or read the 'currentposition' variable with some other technique.

Can anybody help me to get on the right track or has an idea to overcome this issue? Thank you in advance.

EDIT provided way more code then before

Comment: I guess the problem is related to the way Arduino reads Serial input. On standard Arduinos there is a very limited buffer for pending input, which might be the problem. Or, you eventually read everything in time but do not store all commands properly until the motor has followed up. But your code snippet does not show anything relevant in that direction.

Comment: This is how it reads:
Other reads work well.

`void initSerialConnection() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void interpretIncomingData() {
  if(!Serial.available()) {
    return;
  }
 receivedData = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
command = getStringSegment(receivedData, ' ', 0);
  if (command.equals("chkposX")){
      chkposX();
      return;
      }
}
 `

Comment: Edit your post and post your code as an update, not as a comment. It kind of hard to read as a comment.

Comment: i improved the code in my original question.

Comment: How often do you call `interpretIncomingData()` ?

Comment: I call `interpretIncomingData()` in the `void loop() {}` section from the Arduino. I assume this runs it all the time. I am able to call as many motor commands as i want so the continous listening from arduino seems to work.